Confusion in kinetic and static friction difference and approaching problems

Is the friction here kinetic since the blocks are moving down. I don't know how to know when to apply kinetic friction and when to apply static fricion. When motion is givien I understand and use kinetic friction but rest of cases I don't understand.

Why are both these blocks moving down with same acceleration after sometime?

Your question needs clarity.  You have posted some solutions but not the question. Your question, Why are both these blocks moving down with same acceleration after sometime? can be answered by working out what the accelerations would have been if the blocks were not in contact.


I don't know how to know when to apply kinetic friction and when to apply static friction

If two objects are moving relative to one another (which they are here, since the blocks are sliding down the inclined plane) then you use the coefficient of kinetic friction to find the friction between them. If two objects are stationary relative to one another then you use the coefficient of static friction.

Why are both these blocks moving down with same acceleration after sometime ?

Your two diagrams give two methods of analysing the same problem. In the first method the two blocks are treated as one single object with a mass of $30$ kg. In the second method the forces on each individual block are analysed, so this method explicitly includes that normal force $N$ that each block exerts on the other. $N$ is ignored in the first method because the two blocks exert equal and opposite forces on each other, so the two normal forces cancel one another if we treat the blocks as one single object.
Note that the two blocks are drawn with a gap between them in the second diagram purely to show the forces more clearly - in reality there is no gap (as in the first diagram).
So it is not surprising that the two methods reach the same answer for the acceleration of the blocks - indeed, we would be surprised if they did not.

Simple answer: for static friction, people tend to loosely say, "$f = \mu N$" but what they really mean is "$|f| <= \mu N$".  You don't necessarily know what the force of static friction is, you just know that it is within some limit.  Sometimes there will be a phrase in the problem that says something like "at the moment slipping begins," and then you can use $f = \mu N$.
In general, friction problems have two parts: the first part is making an assumption about whether the problem is static or dynamic and doing the calculations.  The second part is going back to check your assumptions.  Is $|f| <= \mu N$?  If not, then there IS relative motion ... but in that case you can assume $f = \mu N$ and re-do the calculation.
Going a little deeper, I would add two things.  The first is that many students treat $f = \mu N$ with the same kind of reverence as $F = ma$ but in fact $f = \mu N$ is a convenient but crude approximation to friction behavior, which can be quite complicated -- something to keep in mind for real world calculations.  The second thing is that texts sometimes use different $\mu$ for static and dynamic situations.  While there is a reason for this (the real world sometimes behaves similarly), it can lead to various numerical complications if you actually try to run simulation code with this assumption.  Best practice for textbooks anyway is to just use one $\mu$.


Is the friction here kinetic since the blocks are moving down. I don't
know how to know when to apply kinetic friction and when to apply
static fricion. When motion is given I understand and use kinetic
friction but rest of cases I don't understand.

The friction is kinetic since the blocks are presumably in motion. You say you don't know how to know when to apply kinetic friction, but then you say when motion is given you understand and use kinetic friction. So you apparently do understand.
The kinetic friction force is generally treated as independent of the magnitude of the relative velocity between the objects, having a magnitude given by
$$f_{k}=\mu_{k}N$$
Where $\mu_k$ is the coefficient of kinetic friction between the object and the surface upon which is slides, and $N$ is component of the force acting on the object normal (perpendicular) to the surface upon which it is sliding.
With regard to the "rest of cases" I assume you mean when motion is not involved.  In those cases the only friction is static friction. The difference between kinetic and static friction is kinetic friction is a force acting opposite to the direction of motion of an object already underway whilst static friction is a force that prevents the onset of motion of an object.
The static friction force is a variable force that matches and opposes the force applied to the object parallel to the contacting surfaces. In terms of the first diagram, these would be the friction forces that prevent the initiation of motion of the two blocks from the static. To determine them you would need to do a free body diagram of each block.
The static friction force on each block will prevent motion so long as the maximum possible static friction force between each block and the surface is  not exceeded. That maximum possible static friction force is given by
$$f_{s-max}=\mu_{s}N$$
where now $\mu_s$ is the coefficient of static friction.

Why are both these blocks moving down with same acceleration after
sometime?

@Farcher has answered this in a comment to your post. To quote it "Your question, why are both these blocks moving down with same acceleration after sometime? can be answered by working out what the accelerations would have been if the blocks were not in contact."
Hope this helps.
